# How do I convert a time string (2 hours 30 minutes) into a decimal so that it becomes 2.5?

Tags: sql, excel, string, time, decimal

In Excel or SQL, how can I convert the time string such as 2 hours 30 minutes into a decimal so that it reads 2.5 hours? This is in an excel spreadsheet so there are multiple values which also includes: 2 hours, 3 hours, 1 hour 15 minutes. Is there anyway to change all of the values using a formula or SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple. Just do following Equation in Excel:

```
Minutes / 60 = Hours in Decimal
```

Example: 2 hours 30min

```
30 / 60 = 0.5  -> 2.5 hours
```

Example 2: 1 hour 15min

```
15 / 60 = 0.25  -> 1.25 hours
```

If you only use minutes: Example 3: 150min

```
150 / 60 = 2.5 hours
```

Its as easy as that :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi

The field is a string which is "2 hours 30 minutes" in which I need to convert it into a decimal using a formula or SQL. Doing the method you suggested involves manually going through each field and changing it to a decimal point. The spreadsheet I have is very big to do that much.

Answer (score 0):

From `2 hours 30 minutes` you can take the hours and then divide the minutes by 60 like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myTime As String

    myTime = "2 hours 30 minutes"
    Debug.Print Round(Split(myTime)(0) + Split(myTime)(2) / 60, 2)

    myTime = "2 hours 35 minutes"
    Debug.Print Round(Split(myTime)(0) + Split(myTime)(2) / 60, 2)

End Sub
```

You can even make a custom function for this:

```
Public Function TimeToDouble(myTime As String) As Double
    TimeToDouble = Round(Split(myTime)(0) + Split(myTime)(2) / 60, 2)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

In excel, add three empty columns next to the time column. Then highlight the column and select "text to columns" select "space" as the deliminator. This will break the data up like this (without dots, they just help with format):

`A  B       C   D
 2  hours   .   .
 3  hours   .   .
 1  hour    15  minutes
 2  hours   30  minutes`

each in their own column.

Then in a fifth column create the equation:
`=A1+C1/60`

Format the column to the number of decimals you want and you'll get the following data:

`E
2.00
3.00
1.25
2.50`

Comment: This will break when there is a "30 minutes" timestring

Comment: No, not if you use space as the delimiter. In the first table I have, it will read the third column (C) as zero and will not put anything after the decimal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your string is this predictable, but I tried a step-by-step script to put together a couple values. You can use a combination of LEFT(), RIGHT() to pry out the values you want to use for calculations, and CAST(col AS NUMERIC) to use the string values in division. Here is a sample that you can run in any session:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TEMP

CREATE TABLE #TEMP (
    [TimeString]            NVARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMP ([TimeString])
VALUES('2 hours 30 minutes')
,('20 hours 45 minutes')
,('3 hours')

SELECT [TimeString]
    ,LEFT([TimeString],2) [Left-side hours]
    ,RIGHT([TimeString],10) [Right-Side Minute]
    ,LEFT(RIGHT([TimeString],10),2) [Left of the right side Minute]
    ,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([TimeString],10),2) AS NUMERIC(24,2)) [Numeric Minutes]
        --Cast as NUMERIC is important for allowing the precision to calculate decimals.
    ,CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([TimeString],10),2) AS NUMERIC(24,2))/60 [Decimal Minutes]
    ,LEFT([TimeString],2)+CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([TimeString],10),2) AS NUMERIC(24,2))/60 [Put hours and decimal minutes together]
    ,CASE WHEN [TimeString] LIKE '%minutes%' THEN LEFT([TimeString],2)+CAST(LEFT(RIGHT([TimeString],10),2) AS NUMERIC(24,2))/60
        ELSE LEFT([TimeString],2) END [Final Column]
FROM #TEMP
```

Output: [image]

The Final Column accounts for the records where there are no 'minutes' in the string. Let me know if this works!